# Configuration whie using Quartz with spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am currently using quartz schedular which comes with spring framework.Our requirement is to schedule a method on daily basis which will call a webservice(only one method on the webservice).My configuration is as below.

```
<bean id="downloadJob" 
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="targetObject" ref="adapter" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getData" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
        <ref bean="downloadJob" />

        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="downloadJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="" /> 

</bean>
```

I am reading the cronExpression value from properties file.
Please provide me some pointers to implement the schedular in better way. i have seen in some other projects where only using quartz with out spring.They are taking care of thread pool and some other properties as below.I am first time working on schedular implementation.Please provide me some suggestions/pointers on how to take care of these below properties while using quartz with spring(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean).Please suggest me if i need to take care of anyother things apart from these.

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 15
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a fine way to implement a scheduler in Spring. The Spring reference has a whole [section on Quartz integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) that should help get you started. For setting Quartz properties, use the SchedulerFactoryBean's [quartzProperties property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setQuartzProperties%28java.util.Properties%29). You'll have to decide yourself if there's anything else to take care of by reading up on [Quartz in general](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/index.html) and learning more about [Quartz configuration](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/1.x/configuration/index.html).

Comment: Could you update the links as they are no longer working